# Unable to change XDEBUG configuration [xdebug.remote_enable]

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have an OS-X setup and using Netbeans IDE for my PHP programming. I have xdebug installed in the following path of

> zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"

Under which I have xdebug.remote_enable set to On..such as 
xdebug.remote_enable = on

This is the desired [Netbeans Xdebug configuration](http://wiki.netbeans.org/HowToConfigureXDebug#How_to_on_MAC_OS_X_Snow_Leopard) recommendation .

And upon viewing my phpinfo:

I get

> xdebug.remote_enable = off

Not sure where it is picking up this information from, and any other xdebug parameter configurations do not alter themselves either.

This is getting me confused as to what is going wrong.

The php version that is running is 5.3.6.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after modifying php.ini? Are there any other php.ini files being read (php and php-cli might be reading different configuration files)?

Comment: Yes I did restart Apache in all cases. I just checked the configuration file and in fact it is a case of the OS X default php.ini file that is being read across command line.  however, should on the browser, it is the MAMP version of php.ini file that is being outputted. Now unless Netbeans is somehow using the default command line installation and yet outputting MAMP phpinfo data, there should not be a problem, right or wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and later found that I was editing the wrong php.ini file. You should edit the file located under /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini and write xdebug.remote_enable = 1