# unable to get xdebug to work

Tags: netbeans, mamp, xdebug

Have been having trouble getting xdebug to work in MAMP - well it seems ok, but I can't get codebug or netbeans to pick up on the port.

Running MAMP with the following:

```
Apache 2.2.23
MySQL 5.5.29
PHP 5.2.17 & 5.3.20 & 5.4.10
APC 3.1.10
eAccelerator 0.9.6.1
XCache 1.2.2 & 1.3.2
phpMyAdmin 3.5.5
SQLiteManager 1.2.4
Freetype 2.4.8
t1lib 5.1.2
curl 7.28.1
jpeg 8d
libpng-1.5.13
gd 2.0.34
libxml2 2.8.0
libxslt 1.1.28
gettext 0.18.1.1
libidn 1.17
iconv 1.14
mcrypt 2.5.8
YAZ 4.0.1 & PHP/YAZ 1.1.5
```

My PHP.ini file includes the following:

```
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.2.17/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-        20060613/xdebug.so"
```

Tried it with and without the additional xdebug settings, only added them in because my phpinfo file shows the values like xdebug.remote_enable=off (might be the problem?)

My PHPInfo file shows the following:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with XCache v1.2.2, Copyright (c) 2005-2007, by mOo
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans


xdebug support  enabled
Version 2.2.1
IDE Key Martin

Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol $Revision: 1.145 $

Directive   Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace   Off Off
xdebug.cli_color    0   0
xdebug.collect_assignments  Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On  On
xdebug.collect_params   0   0
xdebug.collect_return   Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable  On  On
xdebug.default_enable   On  On
xdebug.dump.COOKIE  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.ENV no value    no value
xdebug.dump.FILES   no value    no value
xdebug.dump.GET no value    no value
xdebug.dump.POST    no value    no value
xdebug.dump.REQUEST no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SERVER  no value    no value
xdebug.dump.SESSION no value    no value
xdebug.dump_globals On  On
xdebug.dump_once    On  On
xdebug.dump_undefined   Off Off
xdebug.extended_info    On  On
xdebug.file_link_format no value    no value
xdebug.idekey   no value    no value
xdebug.max_nesting_level    100 100
xdebug.overload_var_dump    On  On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.profiler_output_name cachegrind.out.%p   cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart Off Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back  Off Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time    3600    3600
xdebug.remote_enable    Off Off
xdebug.remote_handler   dbgp    dbgp
xdebug.remote_host  localhost   localhost
xdebug.remote_log   no value    no value
xdebug.remote_mode  req req
xdebug.remote_port  9000    9000
xdebug.scream   Off Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace Off Off
xdebug.show_local_vars  Off Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta   Off Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger Off Off
xdebug.trace_format 0   0
xdebug.trace_options    0   0
xdebug.trace_output_dir /var/tmp/   /var/tmp/
xdebug.trace_output_name    trace.%c    trace.%c
xdebug.var_display_max_children 128 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 512
xdebug.var_display_max_depth    3   3
```

Have confgiured Netbeans as follows:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html

codebug as follows:

http://www.codebugapp.com/documentation/

Neither are picking up the port.

Firewalls have been turned off.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Gave myself the clue to the answer which I found here:

[Unable to change XDEBUG configuration [xdebug.remote_enable]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286957/unable-to-change-xdebug-configuration-xdebug-remote-enable)

I was editing the wrong PHP.ini file - although I did still need the additional xdebug values

Was editing

```
/Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.2.17/php.ini
```

When it should have been

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
```